# How to represent any text in text() method of xpath in selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a text in a paragraph tag

```
<p class="lead ng-binding">                     Showing all 50 toys available at Delhi store                 </p>
```

I used `//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'Showing all 50 toys available at Delhi store'`

and it located successfully, but what I need is the 50 and store name can be anything. So I need something which I can use to represent anything while locating this element. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what is exact output you want to get? Do you want to extract `"50"` from paragraph or you want to "ignore" `"50"` in your XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to extract `"50"` from paragraph:

```
xpath = "//p[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), 'Showing all') and contains(normalize-space(text()), 'toys available at')]"
paragraph = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
value = paragraph.text.split("Showing all ")[-1].split()[0]
print(value) # "50"
```

XPath should allow you to fetch paragraph that starts-with `"Showing all..."` subsrtring and also contains `"...toys available at..."` substring, so you don't have to specify number and store name in XPath

P.S. As you didn't specify the programming language you use I provided example of solution in Python. Add appropriate tag if you want solution in specific language

Comment: Thank you very much @Andersson, it worked for me. Actually I wanted to locate an element whose text contents changes with the number of results and the location. Your provided xpath solved my problem. Thank you again :-)